# installing GEOS, PROJ, GDAL/OGR into a python virtualenv on Mac OS X

Tags: gdal, ogr, osx

I am trying to setup an isolated python virtualenv to work on GIS projects on my Mac OS X. Sounds like I will need to install the GEOS, PROJ, GDAL/OGR from the kyngchaos site here http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks and not easy_install it into my virtualenv. Is that accurate?

The downloads available on kyngchaos are pkg installers and not just an egg or bdist of python modules. So, I am not very sure as to what else the installer is doing to the environment other than just copying files to `/Library/Framework/geos.framework` folder.

How would I go about installing a specific version of GEOS, PROJ, GDAL/OGR into my new python virtualenv? I would appreciate your help/suggestions on this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each Framework of Kyngchaos is in the PATH, it is easy. Every framework has a Unix folder, with the libraries for compiling things like  pyproj or geos python wherever you want, even in a private Python environment (I've never had a problem)

The only problem is that Gdal python is in the Gdal Framework. But in site-packages there a file gdal.pth

gdal.pth file:

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(0,'/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.7/Python/site-packages')
```

if you do not want to compile it yourself, copy this file in your isolated python virtualenv

Comment: having installed those projects by hand, through 3rd party installers (fink/macports/whatever) and through other means I will guarantee to you that the best way is through Kynchaos! +1000

Comment: @Ragi Yaser Burhum – I'm beginning to agree with you! I have been trying to use Fink to install necessary dependencies to run Cartopy in Python. I'm getting: "OSError: Could not find lib geos_c or load any of its variants" even though libgeos_c.dylib is at /sw/opt/libgeos3.6.1/lib and I've added that path to .bash_profile. I don't suppose you have any pearls of wisdom based on your experiences with fink?

Comment: @use use Homebrew :)

Comment: @RagiYaserBurhum ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use OSX you can easily avoid installation complexities by installing [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)!

After this the only commands you will need to enter are:

```
brew install gdal
```

It will automatically install also proj and geos because they are gdal dependencies.

Comment: I don't believe this addresses the issue of accessing gdal from within a virtualenv (I tried it and it did not work)

Comment: you can use `brew install gdal` as long as you create your venv with the --system-site-packages flag, see my answer here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/345248/155269

Answer (score 4):

I make replicable Python/C/C++ GIS environments using virtualenv and zc.buildout. My ichpage https://github.com/sgillies/ichpage project is a little dated but could serve as a template for an up-to-date one (like the one I use for my Pleiades site development work and deployments). Blog post about it at http://sgillies.net/blog/856/i-can-has-python-and-gis-environments/.

Answer (score 3):

Virtualenv allows you to provision a private *Python* environment, but does not extend to system libraries outside of the Python universe. The three packages you mentioned are all C/C++ applications at their core, so while they have interfaces for use with Python, they cannot be packaged without interacting with the C libraries (libc on up).

Because of the difficulty installing those packages from scratch, particularly on OS X, you may want to think about running a sandboxed virtual machine using something like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and install the packages through apt on that sandboxed machine: while it is possible to do the same on OS X, it probably isn't worth the effort.

Comment: This is a good recommendation.  I followed this approach using Fusion, not VirtualBox, but I might try Virtual Box next time.  I used CentOS for the OS in the box.  (Not the best OS choice due to the stable nature and older versions of Python, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I found a good blog post that provides another solution that worked in my case:

http://linfiniti.com/2013/02/installing-python-gdal-into-a-python-virtualenv-in-osx/

The only difference to the blog post is that I had to do is to download the correct version of GDAL that matched the kyngchaos packages. In my case I was using the GDAL framework version 1.10, so the following install was successful

```
source venv/bin/activate
pip install --no-install GDAL==1.10.0
cd venv/build/GDAL
python setup.py build_ext\
    --gdal-config=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/unix/bin/gdal-config\
    --library-dirs=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/unix/lib/\
    --include-dirs=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/Headers/
```

Then leave the GDAL directory and install without download

```
cd ~
pip install --no-download GDAL
```

UPDATE: You might have to add some env vars before calling setup.py for the compilation step to work ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/))

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

Yellowcap's [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/109895/76151) above worked for me with some minor tweaks:

pip install --no-install is no longer an option. Instead, inside the env directory:

```
pip download GDAL==1.11.2 (or whichever version you want)
```

Unzip the downloaded directory and cd into it:

```
tar -zxvf GDAL-1.11.2.tar.gz
cd GDAL-1.11.2
```

pip install --no-download is also no longer an option. Instead stay in the GDAL directory and run:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

[NextGIS installer](https://my.nextgis.com/downloads/software/installer/nextgis-setup.dmg) have isolated gdal, geos, proj, etc. and python bindings (Python 2.7) to gdal. Installation not affected on system libraries (only several environment variables in bash_profile).

Answer (score 0):

After 9 years, it's still an issue to install GDAL and co. As said, if you don't go with `conda` but `brew`, you cannot access GDAL from the virtualenv. You then have 3 options:

1. Create a virtualenv with the flag `--system-site-packages`,
2. Use [pygdal](https://github.com/nextgis/pygdal),
3. Link the recipe from brew.

Here is how to do it:

```
brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac
brew install osgeo-gdal
brew install osgeo-gdal-python

# link gdal
brew link osgeo-gdal --force
brew link osgeo-gdal-python --force

# create venv
python3 -m venv venv && . venv/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip setuptools 

# install gdal
pip install gdal
```

Careful, about your PATH. You may have GDAL with a Postgres installation, and this will conflict.