# Why doesn't installing GDAL from `pip` work on Ubuntu 18.04x64

Tags: python, gdal, pip, conda

Does anyone know why the `pip` install of `gdal` never seems to work? I am asking out of genuine curiosity and don't intend to sound negative. I have a related downstream packaging issue with GDAL as a dependency, but was just wondering why this installation has persisted for such a long time. Because of the `pip` errors, I actually have to develop my package for `conda-forge` instead of PYPI. My usual workaround for `gdal` is to use the `conda-forge` installation of `gdal`.

I get all kinds of errors whenever I try and install `gdal`. I get different kinds of errors each time I try and install it.

For example, if I use Anaconda to create a new environment:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.6
conda activate myenv
pip install gdal
```

I will either get errors about broken `wheels` or I get an error such as this about `gcc`:

```
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /media/xxx/t_gdal/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/xxx/pip-install-bmel7ik_/gdal/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/xxx/pip-install-bmel7ik_/gdal/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/xxx/pip-record-df_uldmb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /media/xxx/anaconda3/envs/t_gdal/include/python3.6m/gdal Check the logs for full command output.
```

Here are other folks who have had similar issues installing `gdal`.

[Python GDAL package missing header file when installing via pip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip)

[How to (re)install gdal in python3 (mac)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229061/how-to-reinstall-gdal-in-python3-mac)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587960/gdal-installation-error-using-pip

[Installing GDAL and OGR for Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9553/installing-gdal-and-ogr-for-python)

Is `gdal` one of the cases where `pip` does not work well, because of all the C and C++ compilation, etc? I was just wondering what the cause was.

Comment: @user2856 yep, I am definitely using the `conda-forge` version of gdal, which works pretty reliably. But I am developing a package that I want to open source, and seems like I have to now use `conda` and `conda-forge` instead of `pip` and PYPI. So if that is the way that things are that is fine, but was just wondering if I can get away with using `pip` alone? That is why I was curious about this.

Comment: @user2856 that makes a lot more sense, and that validates kinda what I imagined was the issue. So `pip` is good at python source packages, but has a harder time with compiled extensions and things. So this is where a package manager like `conda` would work better in most cases.  That clarifies the underlying issue. Thanks again for all of your help.