# Installing python-mapscript in virtualenv

Tags: python, mapserver, installation, mapscript

I am on a django project where I want to use the python implementation of the [mapserver mapscript](http://mapserver.org/mapscript/) library. I was able to install mapserver and python-mapscript from source.

However, due to the project setup I am forced to run django in a [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/) that does not allow site-packages in my virtual environment.

Since mapscript is installed as a global site-package my django app can't see the mapscript installation. When I try to install mapscript through `pip install mapscript` I get an error `'mapserver.h' file not found`.

How can I install python-mapscript in my virtual environment?

I thought of copying the installed egg into my virtual environment, but I am not sure if that is possible.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues/4267

Comment: You can't install site-packages in your virtualenv? That's the whole point of using a virtualenv.

Comment: I am not trying to install the site-package per se in the virtualenv. I just wanted to point out that my installation works fine outside virtualenv, but I don't know how do an installation within it.

Comment: Ohhh. So when you are doing ``pip install mapscript`` are doing it from within the activated virtualenv (``source bin/activate``) and getting the error that mapserver.h is not found?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it, outside the virtualenv I was able to install mapscript from source, but in the virtualenv I dont konw how to do that and pip does throw that error.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6360/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just faced the same problem and solved it by copy the `mapscript.py` and `_mapscript.so` into my virtual env.

```
cd venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
cp /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_mapscript.so .
cp /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mapscript.py .
```

At least the following script in a python web-app worked fine, based on the mapserver demo files I got [here](http://www.mapserver.org/introduction.html#get-demo-running).

```
...
import mapscript
map = mapscript.mapObj(mapfile_path + "itasca.map")
img = map.draw()
img.save("/var/www/img/tmp/mapscript_test_itasca.png")
...
```

This is just a test script, which proved that the mapfile is correctly read and the picture is created.

I you are not allowed to copy, you may try your luck with `pip install` again by adding the include paths:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/mapserver -I/usr/include/gdal" pip install mapscript
```

I needed the packages `libmapserver-dev`, `libgd-dev`, `libgdal-dev` and `libproj-dev` installed to get the compiling running to start and ran into many errors. The log showed:

```
Using version 5.6.3.0 (newest of versions: 5.6.3.0, 5.4.2.1, 5.02.2.33)
```

While Mapserver 6.4 is installed on my system (and 7.0 just came out), there seems to by a compatibility issue. According to [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mapscript) the most recept `mapscript` pip package is version `5.6` from 2010.

I guess you can't install it via `pip` unless you use `mapserver 5.6` or older.