# MapScript with Python 3

Tags: python, mapscript, django-raster, django-wms

I am trying to build raster summarizing features into a GeoDjango webmap,
and would like to use the [django-raster](https://django-raster.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [django-wms](https://django-wms.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.11/) packages to do so. I believe that I have them set up correctly, but am hitting errors when I try to install the MapScript Python bindings for MapServer (necessary for
django-wms).

I believe there is a compatibility error with Python 3 and MapScript, but
am unsure of how to resolve them. I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83345/how-to-install-python-mapscript-in-a-virtualenv) forum-post & GitHub [issue](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues/4748) , but unfortunately my software development knowledge is not solid enough to make much sense of them.

Has anyone compiled MapServer/MapScript with Python 3 recently, or know of any information per updating the software for compatibility with Python 3+?

Comment: You should post the error you are getting.