# Install OSGeo module in virtualenv

Tags: python, gdal, installation, mac, osgeo

How can you install the osgeo module in a virtualenv? I downloaded QGIS using KyngChaos (www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis) following https://arset.gsfc.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/land/webinars/Advanced_Land_Classification/ARSET_Downloading_Installing_QGIS_Final.pdf (without the optional modules "GDAL Extras")

It seems to build all of the Python frameworks on my system's version of Python. I tried adding the path export `PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH` to my bash profile but I still get `ImportError: No module named osgeo`.

I also tried following [Install GDAL python package in virtualenv on mac](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198425/install-gdal-python-package-in-virtualenv-on-mac) but get this error when I try to `python setup.py build`:

```
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3172:10: fatal error: 'cpl_vsi_error.h' file not found
#include "cpl_vsi_error.h"
```

The error persists after I modify the config.cfg file to my brew installed GDAL

```
[build_ext]
# gdal_config = ../../apps/gdal-config
gdal_config = /usr/local/bin/gdal-config
```

Any ideas?

I can't use my system version of python because I have OpenCV installed in a virtualenv.

Comment: please don't thank in advance, please give thanks by voting on answers